# printf("%d", &a) output a random number 36767236871

Tags: c, hex, printf

What is difference between `%d` and `%p` when printing?

For example:

```
int main() {
     int a = 9;
     printf("%d\n", &a);
     printf("%p\n", &a);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: %d=1587542172
%p=000000ab5e9ff890  here it printed hexa but what is above printed by %d

Comment: Read the [printf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). `%d` requires an `int` variable but you have given it a pointer. `int` and pointer are not interchangable.

Comment: If you use sensible compiler settings, it should not compile or at the very least provide a warning that you're passing `int *` not `int`. Change your compiler settings to provide warnings and treat warnings as errors. Most of us do.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function supports different conversions for different types of arguments: `%d` produces a decimal representation (`d` for *decimal*) for an argument of type `int`, `%p` produces a system dependent representation of a `void` pointer (`p` for *pointer*)

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you pass the address of an `int` variable, hence a type `int *` where `printf` expects an `int` for the `%d` conversion: This has undefined behavior
- you pass the address of an `int` variable, hence a type `int *` where `printf` expects an `void *` for the `%p` conversion: This has undefined behavior
- you did not include `<stdio.h>` and you call the function `printf` without a proper prototype: the prototype inferred from the call is incompatible with the actual definition, so the behavior is undefined.

The output you observe is the result of undefined behavior: it is unpredictable and potentially irreproducible: on my system, I get different output every time I run the program, even without recompiling. Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    int a = 9;

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&a);

    printf("0x%"PRIxPTR"\n", (uintptr_t)&a);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)NULL);
    printf("0x%"PRIxPTR"\n", (uintptr_t)NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9
0x7fff54823844
0x7fff54823844
0x0
0x0
```

The last conversion takes a `uintptr_t`, an integer type large enough to store an integer representation of a pointer.  On my system, OS/X, the `%p` conversion produces the same output as `0x%x` for the corresponding integer type.

Answer (score -1):

Will output something like:

```
-1807747332, 
00000083943ff6fc
```

The format specifier converts the value of the corresponding variable to the format data type. %d converted it to a signed integer. If you use %p it simply treats the value as the memory address of a pointer and prints it in hexadecimal.

Comment: Passing incorrect variable types to `printf` is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: so %d in this example just printing random value

Comment: Formally, they are called format specifiers. printf is a function that can have arguments of different data types, and so there must be a way to specify what data type is provided for printf functions. Now these tokens tell what the provided data type is. This is predefined and each data type has a unique format specifier. So when you want to print a character variable use %c, int, %d use a string, use %s, use %p to print the address as stored in the pointer. Here's what you need to do to get an idea, write some code, and use a conflicting format specifier in your printf file.

Comment: @rosterrz it is not random in your case but it is not guaranteed to be not random, thus undefined behavior

Comment: @rosterrz it's not "random value" but Undefined Behavior. It can crash or [make nasal demons fly out of one's nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)